# How to fetch data with days difference in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like.

```
ID      Var      Date1                  Date2
1       A        2017-06-01 12:05:18    2017-06-25 06:08:04
2       B        2017-07-01 18:05:22    2017-07-20 18:25:04
3       C        2017-07-10 23:09:15    Null
4       D        2017-07-10 14:09:45    2017-08-01 09:45:12
5       E        2017-08-12 12:05:18    2017-09-04 07:15:04
```

I want to fetch those rows where difference between `Date2` and `Date1` is >10 days.

I have tried below mentioned query but it didn't work.

```
select ID from table_1 where date(Date2-Date1)>10 and date(Date1)>'2017-05-01';
```

And how to add column which show the days difference.

Comment: You said Date2 and Date 1 , but you seem to be using the other way Date1-Date2 shouldn't it be Date2-Date1

Comment: Try `Date2-Date1` without `date()` or `datediff(Date2,Date1)`.

Comment: A Datediff function where 1 or both dates are null will return null and will not be seen by > < = <> which may not be what you want.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DATEDIFF() function:

Quoting the manual's page :

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation

Try the below query :

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE DATEDIFF(Date2,Date1)>10;
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056aab/4

Answer (score 1):

You have to use timestamp value

```
select ID from table_1 t1 where (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.Date2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.Date1)>864000)
```

where 864000 is the timestamp value of 10 days

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from table where DATEDIFF(Date1, Date2) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select ID from table_1 where Date2-Date1>10;
```

Comment: `date(Date2-Date1)` won't work. But `Date2-Date1 > 10` or `(Date2-Date1) > 10` or `datediff(Date2,Date1)`  will.